# How to add Image inside a textbox in ext-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs

I have created a textbox using below code. I want one search image inside this textbox How can we get that?

```
So Basically I have created one Table with Footer so I want there one textbox inside the textbox search button should be there and on that button want to call other function.

I have made below changes still I am just getting normal textbox only. Not getting search button could you please check.

var ALIASGRID = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                store : ALIASGRIDStore,
                stripeRows : true,
                hideHeaders : true,
                id : "ALIASGRID",
                region : 'center',
                clicksToEdit : 1,
                autoHeight : true,
                viewConfig : {
                    markDirty : false
                },
                columnLines : true,
                columns : [ {
                    id : 'Test',
                    header : 'Test',
                    dataIndex : 'Test',
                    width : 30,
                    editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    triggers: {
                        search: {
                            cls: 'x-fa fa-search',
                            handler: function (field, trigger, eOpts) {}
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    renderer : renderTooltipAndId
                }],
                listeners : {
                    beforeedit : function(grid) {
                        if (!attributeMgrEnabled) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        // console.log(grid);
                    }
                }
            });
            
var ALIASFOOTER = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                enableHdMenu : false,
                id : 'ALIASFOOTER',
                height : 19,
                store : ALIASFOOTERStore,
                columns : [ {
                    id : 'Test',
                    header : 'Testing.',
                    resizable : false,
                    width : 30
                }]});           
                
                
// Table that shows empty rows & a footer
            var layoutTable1 = new Ext.Panel({
                width : 470,
                items : [ ALIASGRID, ALIASFOOTER ],
                renderTo : 'AliasTable'
            });
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIAlM.png)

I am not sure can we add image for this textbox because this is one table and inside that for one text box I want search image inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers for that purpose, see [documenation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-triggers).

Change the `editor` config for the column like this (the default search trigger icon looks like a combobox dropdown selector, that's why I suggest setting a custom icon with `cls`; but you can choose anything you want):

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    triggers: {
        search: {
            cls: 'x-fa fa-search',
            handler: function (field, trigger, eOpts) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Peter for your respose.

I want to add one custom image (like search only) inside the textbox how I can able to add that?

Comment: You mean not a predefined icon like FontAwesome? This example I send adds an icon within the text box, is it don what you need?

Comment: I have modified the above post. I pasted what I did but still I am not able to see textbox with search Icon. Please let me know if is there any other mistake. Thanks

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3n1t), double click n `Name`. Is it what you need? Please prepare a working fiddle with you code so that I can check it.

Comment: No I do not want to use fiddle. I just want one table with one of the column having textbox with search button and on that search button I want to call other function thats it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added Table image as well and I also added my code in main post but some how It is not going inside the trigger could you please tell me is there anything wrong.

Comment: Sorry without a working Fiddle that demonstrates your problem I can't help. For example I don't know your Ext JS version and toolkit, I don't what is `EditorGridPanel` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please tell me by using above code how I can make 2 or 3 column from the table make not editable.